Issue with disk layout
I'm an old school Linux/UNIX System Engineer (retired after 30 years) and have my set ways in which I want the disk layout to be. Root should be separate and small, /var is for logging and you don't want var to fill up on the / filesystem and cause a crash, /opt is for optional software, /usr/local/bin should also be separate. Putting root and everything else in a 1TB volume does not make any sense whatsoever to me. The Ubuntu installer is not as robust as I'd like and I have very few options to tailor the volumes the way I want.
Is there a better way to install Ubuntu that through the limited built-in installer?

You don't mention what Ubuntu product you're talking about, as Ubuntu has many installers. Ubuntu Server is using the subiquity installer, Ubuntu Desktop uses ubiquity for older releases & ubuntu-desktop-installer for the last three releases (with an legacy ISO using ubiquity too for some), and flavors using either ubiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer or calamares depending on release & that is just for amd64!  There is the "Something else", "Manual Partitioning" etc. option that gives you some control; but which installer are you asking about?

You can set up the partitions any way you like prior to install and then install using "something else".

"Root should be separate and small" ~ Do you mean /boot?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
